# Changing the username for a logged on user with FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net

I'm using FormsAuthentication in my ASP.NET application (not the whole asp.net membership).

When a user logs on I validate against the database and use the following code to create an authentication cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
```

My question is, how do I handle a user changing their username?  As the cookie has a different username, my application crashes.

Can I modify the authentication token, or do I just log the user out?

Comment: This link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301342/formsauthentication-handling-a-change-of-username